# Problem with column being forced as primary-key

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, pgadmin

I am new to postgresql and having some problem when creating a table using pgadmin gui. I define a column named id as integer primary-key and another column named idchat as integer not null. But, after saving the table definition the column named idchat was the one saved as primary-key while the column named id is not a primary-key.

After a few tries I found this will happen when a second column name starts  with 'id'. Is this an expected behavior?

regards

Comment: This is likely the behaviour of pgadmin. Postgres itself does not cause this. You can use a tool like https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4ae6c9d99266bba4e73b43307a704fc9 to experiment with

Comment: I strongly recommend that you deploy changes to your data model in a controlled way that can be repeated on different databases. Have a look at - for example -  https://flywaydb.org/download/community. There are others as well. I have not tried my self but here is an implementation in python: https://pypi.org/project/pyway/

Comment: Don't rely on GUIs to create your tables. Write a proper SQL script that contains exactly the   `CREATE TABLE` statement you want, store that script in your Git repository from where you can re-run it any time